# trying to load data in option of dop downl list in vue js , and fetching data from axios api and in mounted function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to fetch data from api and load it into the option tags but giving me the error
is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, I am unable to do If someone can help

here is my code

```
  <b-field  label="Publiser">
    <b-select  v-model="model.publisher"  placeholder="Select a Publisher">

        <option v-for="(item,index) in publisher_array"  :key="index" value="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>

        <!-- <option value="2">Option 2</option> -->
    </b-select>
</b-field>
```

and here is my script tags

```
 export default {

    data() {
    return {
        apis : new api(),
        hasError:true,
        model: {
        file:null,
        name:"",
        platform:"",
        genre:"",
        release_date:new Date(),
        no_of_player:"",
        publisher:"",
        publisher_array:[]
        }
    }
},

mounted() {
    new api().get('api/publisher/view').then(result=> {
      this.publisher_array=result.data;
      console.log(this.publisher_array)
  }).catch((err)=> {
      console.log(err);
  });
},
```

in console log I can see my data but not in render function

Answer (score 0):

So it's rendering before the data comes in, and so it isn't reactive here. You can use `this.$forceUpdate()` at the end of the async function, or you can set another boolean to trigger start false and flag to true when the async function is complete, then use `v-if` on the component.

Answer (score 0):

Are the options supposed to come from `model`, or are they supposed to come from the component's `data` directly? If they're supposed to come from `model` then you'll need to specify `model.publisher_array` in the `option` tag, then set `model.publisher_array = data` (instead of `this`) when you get the data from the API.

If the array should come from the component's data directly, then all you have to do is specify an empty `publisher_array` in data:

```js
data () {
    return {
        publisher_array: [],
        apis: new api(),
        // And so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank I have figured out this already and yes you are right . :)